# Windows Phone 7 background service

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-service

Can a background service be created in WP7 which uses GeoCoordinateWatcher to send data at a specific interval given. What I need exactly is to develop a lightweight WP7 background service that sends latitude and longititude to a wcf server after given MovementThreshold is passed. From what I read, this is not totally achievable in WP7. Is there any workaround that can help me?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do a service which does this every 30 minutes - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202941(v=VS.92).aspx

But if you need more frequent access than that, then the only current possibility is for the user to run your app under their lockscreen.

Comment: Im interested in that, too. Could you provide a link to this "run your app under the lockscreen" possibility?

Comment: Try searching... http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=wp7+run+app+under+lockscreen ... if that really doesn't help then ask a new question.